# C++ errors while compiling

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to compile a game, but getting 100+ errors like:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\cctQCagR.o: In function `load_image(std::string)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4bd4): undefined reference to `std::string::c_str() const'
C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\Temp\cctQCagR.o: In function `createShip(float, float)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4da4): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4dbc): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> cons
t&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4de4): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e04): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e1c): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e28): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e40): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> cons
t&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e60): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e70): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e98): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4eb8): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4ed0): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4ef4): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f04): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\Temp\cctQCagR.o: In function `load_files()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5164): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x517c): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_tra
its<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> cons
t&)'
```

Comment: You are linking against your C++ standard library, right?

Comment: You're getting linker errors. Are all the libraries involved using the same version of the same compiler, using the same runtime settings?

Comment: Can you paste the command that you're using to compile?

Comment: Using: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ............ to compile

Comment: You need to post more context to your question.  What, for example, is contained in Particle_Engine.h (post the code), or is it a third-party header?  Also, you should tell us the entire command you're using when compiling.

Comment: You shouldn't change a question to something totally else. Accept an appropriate answer to your original question and then start a new question with your new problems. I went in and did a rollback to your original question so that the answers still make sense.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I believe you're trying to compile main.cpp with gcc instead of g++.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    std::string bla;
    bla = "BLA BLA";
    printf("%s\n",bla.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

If you build the above code snippet with gcc you get the errors you mention.
If you use g++ it build ok, this makes sense since g++ will make sure all the proper stuff it put together when build C++.

Comment: What is the consideration of gcc to leave it out?

Comment: @xji gcc compiles C, g++ compiles C++. Your code is probably C++ so that's why it doesn't work with gcc.

Answer (score 33):

You need to link your binary with libstdc++. You need to explicitly specify it in command line if using gcc:

```
gcc -lstdc++ tmp.cpp
```

If using g++, libstdc++ will be linked by default:

```
g++ tmp.cpp
```

Comment: This seems to be a more valid answer. Was the same for clang as well.