# gcc -funit-at-a-time causing compile to fail

Tags: c++, mysql, gcc

we have started linking our application with `-libmysqlcppconn-static` for **MySQL** support.

When we compile for debugging everything is ok, but when we compile for release using `gcc -O2` we get errors.

We have tracked down the offending compiler option to be `-funit-at-a-time`.
We get may errors of the form:

> libmysqlcppconn-static.a(mysql_connection.cpp.o): In function
>   `sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::getSavepointId()':
>   mysql_connection.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to`
>   std::allocator: :allocator()'
>   mysql_connection.cpp:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to
>   `std::allocator ::~allocator()'

We are working around this for now by including `-fno-unit-at-a-time`. Any insight into how we can correct this would be appreciated

Comment: What's your gcc version?

Comment: this happens on both our old gcc version 3.4.6 server, and our newer gcc version 4.4.7 servers

Comment: upon further review, -fno-unit-at-a-time works on the 3.4.6 compiler, but has no affect on the 4.4.7.  We still get the errors when linking with that compiler.

Comment: are you statically linking the mysql connector into the release version ?

Comment: yes, we are using static linking

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ errors while compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081815/c-errors-while-compiling)

Answer (score 0):

it might be because you are using using gcc to compile the code.. try using g++ to compile the file
otherwise try using following command
gcc -lstdc++ file.cpp